# javascript: setting array index value won't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, null

I have an array of divs called "array" that I gathered from the DOM using getElementsByTagName. One of the divs is null (at "nullindex"), and I want to switch its location with the location of one of the other divs (at "index"). I tried:

```
array[nullindex] = array[index];
array[index] = null;
alert(array[index].innerHTML + "," + array[nullindex].innerHTML);
nullindex = index;
```

This should switch the locations of the divs and set "nullindex" to its new location, right? But the alert call produces the same innerHTML for both, meaning the div was copied, not switched, and what's supposed to be null is not. So the next time I'm iterating through to find the div I want, it's still at its original position. HELP!!

Comment: note: I think this has something to do with pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the 'array' returned from getElementsByTagName is not an actual array. Before manipulating the elements, run this code:

```
array = Array.prototype.slice.apply(array);
```

Comment: I decided to just edit attributes of the divs (id, to be specific) to reflect movement changes, instead of changing the order in the array. Thank you for your help!

Comment: since the answer solves the original posted question, make sure you click the accept tick over that-a-way <--